# Overriding page pagination

Tags: pagination

Does anybody know if there is a way / script that will allow for example my gallery pages to display in a lazy load (continuous scroll) style?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Also can this be copied and used across multiple templates?

Answer (score 0):

Not tried these myself, but they state they resolve the exact thing you're asking for...

Try this [Infinite Scroll add-on](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/infinite-scroll).

Or this one [Ajax Pagination](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ajax-pagination-lsv).

Answer (score 0):

Create an non-hidden template, let's say `pages/list`, for your list of entries and set `paginate="hidden"`:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news" limit="10" paginate="hidden"}
    <h2>{title}</h2>
    {body}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

From the [documentation](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/pagination.html#paginate):

> "hidden: The navigation text and links will not appear, but your entries will be paginated. (This is useful for things like JSON.)"

On the first page, call it as an `embed`:

```
{embed="pages/list"}
```

On your JS, keep calling it and increasing the pagination offset on the same amount used on the `limit` parameter: `/pages/list/P10`, `/pages/list/P20`, `/pages/list/P30`, etc, etc...